# How to write a function to compare two strings alphabetically?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

If `a="formula"` and `b="formulab`" are two strings, how can the function compare which string comes after the other and return a true or false value?
We know string `b` will come after, but how to determine that using the function?

```py
def alphabet_order(a,b):
    if len(a) > len(b):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

I am getting the length of the strings, but how can I sort the strings lexicographically and compare them?

Comment: how can i write that in a function? as I will have to call the function for the two variables 'a' and 'b' which are strings

Comment: https://pastebin.com/tjcK9DsG
this only sorts a string, it doesn't compare between 2 string but you can sort the string and then compare like this: `sorted_string_a > sorted_string_b`

Answer (score 1):

Python compares strings lexicographically based on *their order in the ascii table* for alphabet (where each letter is essentially assigned a value).

Here is a link to the numeric order: https://www.asciitable.com/

So you now have two options:

1. compare by length (using `len()`).
2. compare by value.

Here is an example of the value comparison:

```py
a = 'hello'
b = 'world'

if a > b:
    print('a > b')
else :
    print('a < b')
```

which returns this:

```
a < b
```

because "hello comes" before "world" in that ordering.

You can wrap the above into a function.